# Error in protocol declaration

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am getting an error as:

> protocol declaration not found

I couldn't find out what's the reason. Now I am using ARC. I doubt that the issue is due to that. Here is the code I am using for protocol declaration

//This is the first page we are declaring the Delegate

.h

```
@protocol ImageDelegate

@optional

-(void)ImageSelected:(UIImage *)ImageName;

@end

@interface GetAddedMovieList : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>{

    id<ImageDelegate> delegate;

}

@property(nonatomic, strong)id<ImageDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

.m

@synthesize delegate;

---

//This is page in which i tried to set delegate. Here I am getting the error.

```
@interface ImageEnlarge : UIViewController<ImageDelegate>{

IBOutlet UIImageView *imgEnlarge; 

NSString *stgImageName;     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are putting an `@interface` on a .m file, are you trying to create a private `@interface`? With an `IBOutlet` declared there?

---

After seeing your edit, I am guessing there is only missing an import on the .h of your ImageEnlarge class.

Comment: That's in another view controller. @interface ImageEnlarge : UIViewController<ImageDelegate>{

IBOutlet UIImageView *imgEnlarge; 

NSString *stgImageName;     
}  not in the view controller in which I m writing the delegate.

Answer (score 0):

I see several (possible) issues in your code.

```
@property(nonatomic, strong)id<ImageDelegate> delegate;
```

delegates should be weak. GetAddedMovieList do now own the delegate by any mean and therefore shouldn't have an impact on its life cycle.

```
@synthesize delegate = delegate;
```

By default @synth uses either ivar_ or _ivar lately. With the latest LLVM @synth aren't necessary anymore btw, neither ivars.

@synthesize outside an @implementation ?

Have you checked your #imports?

Comment: I had tried with weak also instead of strong. I referred many post and did what the reply of those post mentioned. Even though I couldn't solve the issue, that I posted myself. Could you please let me know what all changes I need to make on existing code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably an import loop. Do you #import the correct file for where you are using the protocol?  And are you importing that file in the protocol file?  If so then you have an import loop. Use forward declaration in the protocol's header instead and that should solve it. (@class)

Comment: Yes I tried all these options, used @class instead of #import. I have imported the correct file in which protocol is declared. The issue is only when ARC is enabled. Otherwise my code works perfectly.

Comment: Have you checked for an import loop?

Answer (score 0):

Try like it.

```
 @protocol ImageDelegate<NSObject>

    @optional

    -(void)ImageSelected:(UIImage *)ImageName;

    @end
```

And also add this property.

```
@property(nonatomic,assign)id<ImageDelegate> delegate;
```

I think it will be helpful to you.

Comment: If @property(nonatomic,assign) was given.showing this error,"Existing ivar 'delegate' for unsafe_unretained property 'delegate' must be _unsafe_unretained"